# Android Television: WOL (Wake On LAN) for accessibility

Tags: accessibility, power-on, android-tv, smart-tv, ethernet

Suppose a disabled user with paralyzed arms is sitting at a wheelchair and utilizing and navigating their phone via voice access or camera switches.

Suppose, now, that the TV is off, that the television, is, an Android television, and that the user wants to turn it on, navigate through the channels, and select some television or application program to watch.

In order for this to happen, the television would have to have a chip, that could be a Bluetooth or WiFi-direct enabled ethernet card, that had the Wake On LAN feature.

With this feature (an advanced feature that used to be found in relatively cheap high end ethernet cards for PC), you can send a data packet over an ethernet cable to a PC that is plugged in but is not on, to turn it on.

The ethernet card could support WiFi, I believe, and implement this feature over WiFi.

Perhaps, it can also be done via Bluetooth.

In either case, it would be ideal.

It would allow the disabled user to turn on the television from their mobile phone.

Users who have trouble finding television and satellite dish television controls could also benefit from this, as they could access the television, quicker, when needed, and, would not have to locate, other, gadgets, to operate their television, and could do all of this from their mobile phone.

I wonder whether Android televisions support this (and whether any hardware-software combination has implemented this to date).

Thank you for your answers.